# ¿Cómo soluciono este error Pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

El problema es que estoy creando un código con un ejemplo pero cuando lo ejecuto me da un error y no puedo solucionarlo.

> Codigo

```
    import pygame, sys
from pygame import *
#Variables Globales
PosX = 900
PosY = 480

class naveEspacial(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.ImagenNave =   pygame.image.load("C:/Users/edwar/OneDrive/Escritorio/Programing/Pygame/imagenes/nave.jpg")

        self.rect = self.ImagenNave.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = PosX / 2
        self.rect.centery = PosY - 30

        self.ListaDisparo = []
        self.vida = True

        self.Velocidad = 20

    def movimiento(self):
        if self.vida == True:
            if self.rect.left <= 0:
                self.rect.left = 0
            elif self.rect.right >= 870:
                self.rect.right = 840

    def disparar(self):
        print("Disparo")

    def dibujar(self, superficie):
        superficie.blit(self.ImagenNave, self.rect)

class Proyectil(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite(self, PosX, PosY)

        self.ImagenProyectil = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/edwar/OneDrive/Escritorio/Programing/Pygame/imagenes/disparoa.jpg")

        self.rect = self.ImagenProyectil.get_rect()

        self.VelocidadDisparo = 5

        self.rect.top = PosY
        self.rect.left = PosX

    def trayectoria(self):
        self.rect.top = self.rect.top - VelocidadDisparo

    def dibujar(self, superficie):
        superficie.blit(self.ImagenProyectil, self.rect)


def SpaceInvader():
    pygame.init()
    ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((PosX, PosY))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Ejemplo")

    ImagenFondo = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/edwar/OneDrive/Escritorio/Programing/Pygame/imagenes/fondo.jpg")

    jugador = naveEspacial()

    DemoProyectil = Proyectil(PosX/2, PosY-30)

    enJuego = True

    while True:

        jugador.movimiento()

        DemoProyectil.trayectoria()

        for evento in pygame.event.get():
            if evento.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if enJuego == True:
                if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if evento.key == K_LEFT:
                        jugador.rect.left -= jugador.Velocidad
                    elif evento.key == K_RIGHT:
                        jugador.rect.right += jugador.Velocidad
                    elif evento.key == K_s:
                        jugador.disparar()

        ventana.blit(ImagenFondo, (0, 0))
        DemoProyectil.dibujar(ventana)
        jugador.dibujar(ventana)
        pygame.display.update()

SpaceInvader()
```

Y cuando lo ejecuto me da este error:

```
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\edwar\OneDrive\Escritorio\Programing\Pygame\Clases_juegos.py", line 92, in <module>
    SpaceInvader()
  File "C:\Users\edwar\OneDrive\Escritorio\Programing\Pygame\Clases_juegos.py", line 63, in SpaceInvader
    DemoProyectil = Proyectil(PosX/2, PosY-30)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
[Finished in 8.241s]
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando inicializas tu clase `Proyectil` veo que no recibes ningún parámetro:

```
class Proyectil(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):  # <--- Aquí
```

Sin embargo, al tratar de instanciar esta clase:

```
DemoProyectil = Proyectil(PosX/2, PosY-30)
```

Puedes apreciar que sí le estás pasando la posición `X` e `Y`. Puedes resolverlo actualizando tu método `__init__` para que reciba esos parámetros:

```
class Proyectil(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, PosX, PosY):  # <--- Aquí
```

Comment: No funciona, lo intente pero me da un error mas grande, te dejo el error aquí: